# Multiple Selection on WebDropDown and Reflect It in Another WebDropDown - Infragistics

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, infragistics

I am having one webdropdown named Speciality and another webdropdown names SubSpeciality.

When I click on one item of Speciality the subspeciality list gets populated.

I have used AutoPostBackFlags-SelectionChanged="On" and OnSelectionChanged="wddSpeciality_Selected" for implementing this.

My problem is : I need multiple selection in Speciality without autopostback the page and once the multiple selection is made then the SubSpeciality should be populated by all the items together.

So if I remove AutoPostBackFlag then the list is not getting populated.

please suggest me As soon as you can.

Can I use any Java Script or Ajax Script to achieve this?

If yes Please give me brief description.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use Update Panel. Disable  closing on the first WDD when item is selected (there is a property for this set to true "EnableClosingDropDownOnSelect") and when the first menu is closed to handle this event (DropDownClosed) and to update the Update Panel containing the second WDD which will cause. Another option is just to do _postback   inside this event and avoid using Update Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a solution something like this?

```
   function WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged(sender, eventArgs){

          var items1 = eventArgs.getNewSelection();

          var count = items1.length;

          var items2 = $find("WebDropDown2").get_items();


          for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
          {
              items2._control.selectItemByIndex(items1[i].get_index(), false, true);
          }
    }


       <ig:WebDropDown ID="WebDropDown1" runat="server" Width="200px"
                       EnableMultipleSelection="true"
                       EnableClosingDropDownOnSelect="false">
           <Items>
               <ig:DropDownItem Selected="False" Text="item 1" Value="">
               </ig:DropDownItem>
               <ig:DropDownItem Selected="False" Text="item2" Value="">
               </ig:DropDownItem>
               <ig:DropDownItem Selected="False" Text="item3" Value="">
               </ig:DropDownItem>
           </Items>
           <ClientEvents SelectionChanged="WebDropDown1_SelectionChanged" />
       </ig:WebDropDown>

       <ig:WebDropDown ID="WebDropDown2" runat="server" Width="200px"
                       EnableMultipleSelection="true"
                       EnableClosingDropDownOnSelect="false">
           <Items>
               <ig:DropDownItem Selected="False" Text="item 1" Value="">
               </ig:DropDownItem>
               <ig:DropDownItem Selected="False" Text="item2" Value="">
               </ig:DropDownItem>
               <ig:DropDownItem Selected="False" Text="item3" Value="">
               </ig:DropDownItem>
           </Items>
       </ig:WebDropDown>
```